# Posting a photo to an album in a Facebook fan page using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm issuing a very annoying problem with Facebook API. If someone could help me that would be great.

I'm using Facebook's JS SDK and what I need to acomplish eventually is to post a photo to a specefic album inside one of the user's fan pages. I did succeed to post a photo to a specific album in the user's profile, however - when it comes to pages.. it's just not working.

The code I'm trying to use is the following:

```
var imgURL = "http://newsimg.ngfiles.com/178000/178187_asfasf.jpg";
FB.api('/ALBUMID/photos', 'post', { 
    message: 'Sweet',
    url: imgURL,
    access_token: 'PAGE ACCESS TOKEN'
}, function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Did you get 'manage_pages' permission? Can you copy the response?

Comment: Of course. I got the 'manage_pages' permission - I manage post a new feed to the page.
Regarding to the response I get - here is the weird thing, I do get the response I supposed to get ({id: ...}) but the photo doesn't exist anywhere, not on the album and not on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just found the problem. In order to post photos to a FB fan page you need also to get the "photo_upload" permission.